# Using scanner to create an object identifier?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, identifier

Is there any way to create the name of an object depending on user input?

eg.

```
Object scan.nextLine() = new Object();
```

Comment: If you don't know the name how are you going to use it?

Comment: Simply put: No.

What do you want to achieve by doing so? If the object name is relevant to the user, the name could as well be a property of the object.

Comment: i think that the answer by @cowls , is the answer to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** it is not possible. There are no *dynamic variables* in Java. Java variable name have to be declared in the source code  during compile time.

If want to store the Object with the user entered values you can try using a `Map` to save the data as below.

```
Map<String, Object> objects = new HashMap<String, Object>();
String name = scan.nextLine();

Object obj = new Object();
objects.put(name, obj); // saving the objects in Map
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do this.

I would suggest having a custom class and store the instanceName:

```
public class MyClass {

    private String instanceName;
    public MyClass(String instanceName) {
        this.instanceName = instanceName;
    }

}

MyClass myObj = new MyClass(scan.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot do that in java. Since you should already have a class defined to create a object of it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways you could fake doing this. You could use a map to give the perception of dynamically named Objects. But since you say you are a beginner, the short answer is no. Make sure you know what you are asking for in your example though. Your example is the equivalent of saying:

```
String line = "foo";
Object line = new Object();
```

My guess would be that's not what you wanted (and isn't possible).

Comment: i think he wants , Object foo = new Object(); , not possible as far as i knwo

Answer (score 0):

Given the line

```
Type variable_name = expression ;
```

The name `variable_name` is simply used in the rest of the scope for referencing the outcome of *expression*. You know that Java is a compiled language, and these names are only useful to the programmer. Once the compiler does its job, it can use a translation table and replace those names with whatever ID it wants.

Since those name don't even exist at runtime, there's no way of choosing the name for a variable at runtime.

However you may need to access an object depending on user input (for example like in PHP variable variables `$$a_var`). Depending on your context, you may use reflection to access instance members, or a simple `Map<String, Object>`. Example with reflection:

```
public class VariableRuntime {

    static class Person {
        public String first, last, city; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Person homer = new Person();

        homer.first = "Homer";
        homer.last = "Simpson";
        homer.city = "Springfield";

        System.out.println("What do you want to know about Homer? [first/last/city]");

        String what = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        Field field = Person.class.getDeclaredField(what);

        System.out.println(field.get(homer));
    }

}
```

The same with a `Map<String, String>`:

```
public class VariableRuntime {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> homer = new HashMap<String, String>();

        homer.put("first", "Homer");
        homer.put("last", "Simpson");
        homer.put("city", "Springfield");

        System.out.println("What do you want to know about Homer? [first/last/city]");

        String what = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

        System.out.println(homer.get(what));
    }

}
```